# Trigger Export Executable Script Command from index.ts

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I’m working on creating a JupyterLab extension that will eventually let users test the power usage of their code, and the first step is to create a button that downloads the contents of a Notebook as an executable script.

This can already be done through File > Export Notebook As… > Executable Script or through the Command Palette with Export Notebook: Executable Script, so I suspect it should be fairly straightforward. I’m having trouble getting this command to run from my index.ts file however; any help would be very much appreciated. I believe my main problem is not knowing how to pass the right argument to notebook:export-to-format but I may be doing something else wrong as well.

I set up the environment with this command and cookiecutter from the Extension Tutorial (Extension Tutorial — JupyterLab 3.0.16 documentation):

conda create -n greencode-ext3 --override-channels --strict-channel-priority -c conda-forge -c anaconda jupyterlab=3 cookiecutter nodejs jupyter-packaging git

cookiecutter GitHub - jupyterlab/extension-cookiecutter-ts: A cookiecutter recipe for JupyterLab extensions in Typescript

Here’s my index.ts file:

```
import {
  JupyterLab,
  JupyterFrontEnd,
  JupyterFrontEndPlugin,
} from '@jupyterlab/application';

import { ITranslator } from '@jupyterlab/translation';

import { ToolbarButton } from "@jupyterlab/apputils";
import { DocumentRegistry } from "@jupyterlab/docregistry";
import { INotebookModel, NotebookPanel, INotebookTracker } from "@jupyterlab/notebook";

import { IDisposable } from "@lumino/disposable";

export class ButtonExtension implements DocumentRegistry.IWidgetExtension<NotebookPanel, INotebookModel> {
    
  constructor(app: JupyterLab) {
      this.app = app;
  }
    
  readonly app: JupyterLab;

  createNew(panel: NotebookPanel, context: DocumentRegistry.IContext<INotebookModel>): IDisposable {
     const { commands } = this.app;
     const command = 'notebook:export-to-format'

     // Create the toolbar button
     let mybutton = new ToolbarButton({
         label: 'Measure Power Usage',
         onClick: () => { 
             alert('You did it');
             commands.execute(command, {formatLabel: 'script'});
          }
       });

    // Add the toolbar button to the notebook toolbar
    panel.toolbar.insertItem(10, 'MeasurePowerUsage', mybutton);
    console.log("MeasPowerUsage activated");

    // The ToolbarButton class implements `IDisposable`, so the
    // button *is* the extension for the purposes of this method.
    return mybutton;
  }
}

/**
 * Initialization data for the greencode-ext3 extension.
 */
const yourPlugin: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: '@your-org/plugin-name',
  autoStart: true,
  requires: [ITranslator, INotebookTracker],
  activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd) => {
    const your_button = new ButtonExtension(new JupyterLab);
    app.docRegistry.addWidgetExtension('Notebook', your_button);
  }
}

export default yourPlugin;
```

Comment: Cross-linking https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/trigger-export-executable-script-command-from-index-ts/9417 were a solution was found, will add an answer if I get more time later.